# How to turn this promise based function into rxjs function?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I have this promise based function and im trying to update it to have the same functionality but use RXJS, im a bit new to rxjs and having a lot of trouble.. any help would be really appreciated

```
  public getBase64ImageFromURL(url: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
      img.onload = () => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        resolve(dataURL);
      };
      img.onerror = error => {
        reject(error);
      };
      img.src = url;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can't you just use `from` function to convert it?

Comment: Have you tried from RxJS operator?

Comment: No from function, has to be fully converted

Comment: As (well) explained in the comments below, the way to go is to wrap it into `new Observable`. That said just as an FYI. If you ever come across an API that you don't have your hand onto that is promise based, you could use `from` as Konrad said above if you need it as the emitter but if you even just need it within an already existing stream (within a switchmap for example), you could return the promise straight away. In a lot of cases rxjs is happy to deal with promises on its own

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straight forward : create a new `Observable` and `next` the same value as the `resolve` !

```
  public getBase64ImageFromURL(url: string): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>((subscriber) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
      img.onload = () => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        subscriber.next(dataURL);
      };
      img.onerror = (error) => {
        subscriber.error(error);
      };
      img.src = url;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!  How exactly would i go about utilizing this function and getting the value now?

Comment: `myObs.subscribe()`  is the way to go !

Comment: Looks good, but I would advise `subscriber.complete()` once all the data is emitted. Since that should always happen after the first emission, I would add that to the end of the `img.onload` callback